# Как сделать на javascript формау Auto reply?

Tags: ajax, javascript, html, php

Как на javascript сделать auto reply форму, чтобы она отправляла по введенному Email сгенерированный код? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Нужен подключенный jquery

eml.php:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
 $to = $_POST['email'];
 $subject = "CODE";
 $message = md5($_POST['email']);
 $from = "noreply@stozharov.ru";
 $headers = "From:" . $from;
 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 echo('ok');
}else{
 echo('email error');
}
?>
```

eml.html:

```
<input type='text' id='email'>
<script type='javascript'>
$.post('eml.php',{email:$('#email').val()},function(data){
  if(data!='ok'){
    alert('Что-то не так с адресом почты');
  }else{
    alert('На почту пришел сгенерированный код');
  }
});
</script>
```